# Find $a$ and $b$ so that the function is continuous in $\mathbb{R}$

Tags: functions, continuity

Can someone help me with this math question?

\begin{equation}
f(x) = \begin{cases}
(ax - a - \pi \sqrt{x})/b \quad \text{if }  x \geq 1 \\
(\arctan\big(\frac{1}{x-1}\big))         \quad \text{if }  x < 1
\end{cases}
\end{equation}

I've tried to solve this for more than 2 hours now and I always get stuck

Comment: Hello, could you comment what have you tried and where have you stuck?

Comment: Hi, i can't really understand how to solve arctan(1/0) since x = 1.
I can't find any tutorial on youtube or google that can help me.

Comment: Which definition of continuous function are you used to?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the function is continuous on $\mathbb{R}$ then it must be continuous at $x=1.$ That is, we must have $\lim\limits_{x\to1} f(x) = f(1).$ We have from the function definition that $\lim\limits_{x\to1^-} f(x)=\lim\limits_{x\to1^-} \arctan\left(\frac{1}{x-1}\right)=-\dfrac\pi2.$ Thus we need to solve for $a$ and $b$ in the following equation: $\lim\limits_{x\to1^+} f(x)=\lim\limits_{x\to1^+}\dfrac{a(x-1)-\pi\sqrt{x}}{b}=-\dfrac\pi2\Rightarrow \dfrac{-\pi}{b}=-\dfrac{\pi}{2}\Rightarrow b=2.$ $a$ can be any value in $\mathbb{R},$ since regardless of what value $a$ takes, $a(x-1)\to 0$ as $x\to 1.$

Comment: Hey Simon, thanks for the answer but can you just explain me how did you go from ax-a to a(x-1)?

Comment: I just factored $a$ out of $ax-a.$ Do you get it now? I used the distributive property.

Comment: Hey yeah I got it, thaks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

At $x=1$, the arctan expression $=-\frac{\pi}{2}.$  The other expression $=-\frac{\pi}{b}$, independent of a.  Therefore for continuity at $x=1$, $b=2$.